# VBA/Excel RANK in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, rank

I am working on creating calculations from a spreadsheet into C#, and I was wondering if C# has a similar method to Rank in Excel?

**Rank in Excel**

> Returns the rank of a number in a list of numbers. The rank of a
>   number is its size relative to other values in a list. (If you were to
>   sort the list, the rank of the number would be its position.)
>
> Syntax
>
> **RANK(number,ref,order)**
>
> **Number**     is the number whose rank you want to find.
>
> **Ref**     is an array of, or a reference to, a list of numbers.
>   Nonnumeric values in ref are ignored.
>
> **Order**     is a number specifying how to rank number.
>
> If order is 0 (zero) or omitted, Microsoft Excel ranks number as if
>   ref were a list sorted in descending order. If order is any nonzero
>   value, Microsoft Excel ranks number as if ref were a list sorted in
>   ascending order.

The same can be achieved through code, but I just wanted to check if there was anything I was missing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, sort of.

```
        SortedList<int, object> list = new SortedList<int, object>();
        // fill with unique ints, and then look for one
        int rank = list.Keys.IndexOf(i);
```

Rank will be an ascending, zero-based position.

You could pretty it up by writing an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Rank(this int[] array, int find)
    {
        SortedList<int, object> list = new SortedList<int, object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            list.Add(array[i], null);
        }
        if (list.ContainsKey(find))
        {
            return list.Keys.IndexOf(find);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
    int[] ints = new int[] { 2, 7, 6, 3, 9, 12 };
    int rank = ints.Rank(2);
```

...but I'm not convinced its the most sensible thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up doing something pretty similar to this, I will post my version shortly.

Answer (score 1):

To get the equivalent of RANK you'll need to get the minimum index of each item when you group:

```
var ranks = list.OrderBy(x => x)
                 .Select((x, i) => new {x, i = i+1})  // get 1-based index of each item
                 .GroupBy(xi => xi.x)        // group by the item
                 .Select(g => new {rank = g.Min(xi => xi.i), items = g})  // rank = min index of group
                 .SelectMany(g => g.items, (g, gg) => new {g.rank, gg.i}) ;   // select rank and item
```

or if you'rs grouping by the property of a class:

```
var ranks = list.OrderBy(x => x.{some property})
                 .Select((x, i) => new {x, i = i+1})  // get 1-based index of each item
                 .GroupBy(xi => xi.x.{some property})        // group by the item's property
                 .Select(g => new {rank = g.Min(xi => xi.i), items = g})  // rank = min index of group
                 .SelectMany(g => g.items, (g, gg) => new {g.rank, gg.i}) ;   // select rank and item
```

Comment: I used a solution similar to @Simon to satisfy my tests, I will take a look at this solution too and update once tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me so far (and it is simpler)

```
public static int Rank<T>(T value, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    return data.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList().IndexOf(value) + 1;
}
```

I used `T` so it can take all numeric types (`int`/`double`/`decimal`).

The usage is similar to Excel

```
int[] data = new[] { 3, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
int rank = Rank(3, data); // returns 2
```

I hope I didn't miss anything