# C# Equivalent Ranking

Tags: c#

I'm translating an old Excel system to C#, and I'm having issues with the Rank.eq function. What I did was 3 lists: The list with the original data, the list with the data of the 1st list ordered and the list with the reversed index of the ordered list; then it compares if the list1 value is equal to the list 2 val, it gets the index of the 3rd list in the same position, if not, it skips to the 2nd value to compare, etc.

What I mean, if I have:

```
1
3
3
5
3
7
9
```

The ranks shows like this:

```
No.   Rank
1      5
3      4
3      4
5      3
3      4
7      2
9      1
```

But what I need is something like this:

```
    No.   Rank
    1      7
    3      4
    3      4
    5      3
    3      4
    7      2
    9      1
```

It should skip some numbers if there are repeated values. How can I do the 2nd example? Thanks.

This is my script, in case needed:

```
int l = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; )
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == listBox2.Items[l].ToString())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = listBox3.Items[l];
                    i++;
                    l = 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    l++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why not make an enumerable class with: `ranked.Rank` and `ranked.Num`?

Comment: Your code sample is nearly impossible to follow. There's no way to tell what data you're manipulating. For example, you have three listboxes and a datagrid. I have no idea what those controls contain. It would be easier to read if you had arrays or maybe Lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of a method that ranks a collection of objects.  By grouping the items and then ordering the groups the results can simply be enumerated, keeping track of the number of items yielded up to that point.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, int>> Rank<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var query = source.GroupBy(x => x)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);

    var rank = 1;
    foreach (var group in query)
    {
        var groupRank = rank;
        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(item, groupRank);
            rank++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how I should use it?

Comment: @user3063952 `var rankedData = unrankedData.Rank();`

Comment: Ok, last question, sorry, I'm kinda new with this. How can I show the data now?

Comment: @user3063952 However you want.  You have a collection of pairs.  Do with it what you will.

Answer (score 0):

My answer on similar question: [VBA/Excel RANK in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337900/vba-excel-rank-in-c-sharp/#45602646)

```
public static int Rank<T>(T value, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    return data.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList().IndexOf(value) + 1;
}
```